# How can I make subsections lose the section number within the section and gain the section number outside it?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

For a paper I am typesetting, the author wants subsections to be written with single numerals.  So far, OK,

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
```

does the job.

Yet frequently, he wants to cite the subsection in a later section, and wants both section and subsection numbers in references; i.e., he wants to quote Section 1.1 from Section 2.

My current workaround is to give both the section and subsection numbers in the reference.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section} \label{sec:first}
\subsection{A subsection} \label{subsect:first} Something cool.
\section{New section}
Now I want to cite the coolness in Section~\ref{sec:first}.\ref{subsect:first}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Printout demonstrating what I'm talking about]

This works fine, *except* that the `hyperref` is set up so that if you click on the first 1, you go to Section 1, not Subsection 1.  Yet I would prefer that both numerals go to the same place in the `hyperref` links.

> I could just wrap each such citation in `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}`'s, but is there  an easier way to add section numbers when citing subsections from a different section?

**Note:** Since I'm using `biblatex`, `titlesec` is not applicable.

Comment: What makes you can't use `biblatex`along with `titlesec`?

Comment: @Bernard, the `biblatex` documentation mentions that `titlesec` can redefine the `section` and `chapter` commands, and hence conflicts with `biblatex`'s usage of these for some reason.

Comment: It's funny that titlesec doesn't mention this. On an other hand, as I tested, I noticed a conflict between `titlesec`and the `amsart` class (biblatex not loaded, hence independent of it).

Comment: The question in the body seems to be on how to fix the 1.1 being two separate links, and this is what the current answers address. The question in the title is different, and does not seem to be answered so far.

Comment: It's a point, @ronno .  Fortunately, in the actual paper, subsections are never cited within their sections so that the answers below are adequate.  Also, it seems that by @Werner's answer, `zref` certainly handles this (if not automatically) by its generality and flexibility.  It would be nice, though, to do this automatically, although a conditional is presumably required.

Answer (score 11):

You could (a) redefine `\thesection` as you're already doing and (b) redefine the macro `\p@subsection`. The macro `\p@subsection`, which governs the material that's prefixed to a cross-reference to an item of type `subsection`, is set up automatically by LaTeX when the counter `subsection` is set up. Its default behavior is to do nothing; here, we change it to insert `\thesection.` immediately before the cross-reference to a subsection-level item.

Because the macro name `\p@subsection` contains the character `@`, it's necessary to encase its redefinition in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection.}
\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{A section} \label{sec:first}
\subsection{A subsection} \label{subsect:first} Something cool.
\section{New section}
Now I want to cite the coolness in subsection \ref{subsect:first}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can redefine the `\@seccntformat` command to use `\mythesubsection` instead of `\thesubsection`, provided the former is defined.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \protect\textup{%
    \protect\@secnumfont\protect\check@format{#1}\protect\@secnumpunct
  }%
}
\newcommand{\check@format}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{mythe#1}{\@nameuse{the#1}}{\@nameuse{mythe#1}}%
}
\makeatother

% removing this line will restore the usual setting    
\newcommand{\mythesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}} % just print the subsection number


\begin{document}
\section{A section} \label{sec:first}
\subsection{A subsection} \label{subsect:first} Something cool.
\section{New section}
Now I want to cite the coolness in Section~\ref{subsect:first}.
\end{document}
```

You might also want to define `\mysubsubsection` in case also `\subsubsection` is used and is numbered.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) allows you to generate specific references based on a set of properties. Below I've defined the property list `sections`, which store the section, subsection and section.subsection as part of the property list what you mark a `\label` (actually, a `\zref@labelbypropertylist`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\usepackage{zref}
\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{sections}
\zref@newprop{section}{\thesection}
\zref@newprop{subsection}{\thesubsection}
\zref@newprop{secsubsection}{\thesection.\thesubsection}
\zref@addprops{sections}{section,subsection,secsubsection}
\newcommand{\zlabel}[1]{\zref@labelbylist{#1}{sections}}
\newcommand{\zref}[2][section]{\hyperref[#2]{\zref@extractdefault{z:#2}{#1}{\textbf{??}}}}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldlabel\label
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1}\zlabel{z:#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection} \label{subsect:first} Something cool.
\section{New section}
Now I want to cite the coolness in Subsection~\zref[secsubsection]{subsect:first} 
(it is Subsection~\zref[subsection]{subsect:first} in Section~\zref[section]{subsect:first}).
\end{document}
```

All the hyperlinks in the output point to the same location.